# How to store tuple and its size in a file in erlang?

Tags: erlang, erlang-otp, erlang-shell

I have created a gen_server that should receive a tuple sent from the erlang shell and write it to a file along with the tuple size.

Example: the input received is `{"A","B","C","D"}`, and it should be written to a file as:

`{"A","B","C","D"};4`

and so on. The gen_server should also receive new inputs and store them in a txt file each on a new line.

I have tried but my code is not generating the required output. Assume I have written basic gen_server code with `start_link`, `init`, `handle_call`, `handle_cast`, `handle_info`, `terminate` and `code_change`.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
go() ->
    Tuple = {"A", "B", "C", "D"},
    Length = tuple_size(Tuple),
    {ok, TupleFile} = file:open("tuples.txt", [append]),
    file:write(TupleFile, 
               io_lib:format("~p;~w~n", [Tuple, Length])
              ),
    file:close(TupleFile).
```

`io_lib:format()` is like `io:format()` except instead of writing the string to the shell, `io_lib:format()` returns the string.

In the shell:

```
1> c(a).
a.erl:2:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
%    2| -compile(export_all).
%     |  ^

{ok,a}

2> a:go().
ok

3> 
BREAK: (a)bort (A)bort with dump (c)ontinue (p)roc info (i)nfo
       (l)oaded (v)ersion (k)ill (D)b-tables (d)istribution
                                                                        

~/erlang_programs% cat tuples.txt
{"A","B","C","D"};4
```

Comment: Nice. Two minor improvements on this are to use io:format/3 instead of file:write/2 + io_lib:format/2 and to use "0p" to not get any line breaks in the middle of the tuples when writing out long tuples. 

ie.
`io:format(TupleFile, "~0p;~w~n", [Tuple, Length]),`